# Identification of a weak and fast-moving pattern

Tags: image-processing, data-processing, post-processing

I am currently doing post-processing of a weak and fast-moving pattern (actually waves, if you are familiar with Schlieren Imaging...)

Now the problem is that, other than by directly showing the raw images and measure by hand, I have no good ways to visualize it neatly or extract any data from it (the main point of the post-processing is to find out the frequency! Or even more ambitiously, the velocity of the wave moving...)

In a nutshell, what I have in mind about the problem is that:

1. The patterns are weak, hence any operation of noise removal would hurt it
2. The background is uneven and noisy
3. The patterns move too quickly: within four or five frames the patterns would pass by the whole range of image

Here are an example of images: I have selected 5 that are representative.

[Image 1 of the series of image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ByZj.png)

[Image 2 of the series of images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCmSi.png)

[Image 3 of the series of images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOEDc.png)

[Image 4 of the series of images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4aM5k.png)

[Image 5 of the series of images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ABHH.png)

Also, to better visualize what is moving, I have made a gif to animate them:
[Animated image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r80cW.gif)

Comment: What have you tried so far? It sounds like problem for the Fourier or wavlets analysis.

Comment: Hi I did try Fourier analysis, but the noise is too much for pixelwise Fourier Transform to work: the power spectrum looks messy and can not read anything reasonable from it.